# How to deal with pie menus that has many items?

Tags: python, pie-menu

I am trying to create a pie menu with 10 items/commands. My pie menu works but I have some items are overlapping in the called pie menu which makes me think that there is a logical/visual limit to number of items that can be on a pie menu which is fine. But how do I create a pie menu that has items more than whatever that logical/visual limit in my Python code in 2.80 release?

thanks

Comment: Could you please post your code or ideally a simplified version of it?

Comment: Original limitation was and likely still is 8 items. A work around for that can be found [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/pie-menus-official-customization/618610/25) posted by semaphore august 2014 by grouping multiple commands into a subpanel layout.

Comment: @Ratt you might be on it, I was thinking that there is a limit to 8 items.  I will take look at the link.